# Android 5: are Button labels capitalized automatically?

Tags: android, android-layout

When I show a custom dialog on Android 5.0, it looks like this:

[image: screenshot]

The words `Yes` and `No` are displayed in all capital letters, although in the source code they are not capitalized.

How can I make them show normally?

This is the code for a Button:

```
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_yes"
            android:layout_width="0sp"
            android:layout_height="50sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/yes"
            android:textColor="@color/txt_orange"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" >
        </Button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. According to [Material Design guidelines](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons.html#) button labels are capitalized. So default button style includes `android:textAllCaps="true"`. You should do not change this if your application designed according to Material Design. But if your application uses custom styles and themes then just add `android:textAllCaps="false"` to your button definition:

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_yes"
    android:layout_width="0sp"
    android:layout_height="50sp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/yes"
    android:textColor="@color/txt_orange"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textStyle="normal" />
```

Answer (score 0):

To uncapitalise them, use the following:

```
android:textAllCaps="false"
```

However, I would advise against this, as they are part of [Material Design Guidelines](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons.html#) in Android Lollipop.